# What is the equivalent of "%" (search a part of a word in SQL) in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like an equivalent of `%` (from SQL) in Python.

For example, if you need to find all the words with an "a" inside, in SQL, you put in the "WHERE" section:

```sql
WHERE city LIKE '%a%'
```

So I want to do the same thing, but with a dataframe in Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame("YOUR DATAFRAME")

# filter on dtype
test = df.select_dtypes([np.object]).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('a').any())
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), you can use `col1.str.contains('a')` to translate the SQL `where col1 like '%a%'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['dog', 'many', 'love', 'play'],'col2':['hh', 'many', 'xxxx', 'yyyy']})                                       

df                                                                                                                                    
# Out: 
#    col1  col2
# 0   dog    hh
# 1  many  many
# 2  love  xxxx
# 3  play  yyyy

# df.query("col1.str.contains('a')")                                                                                                    
# Out: 
#    col1  col2
# 1  many  many
# 3  play  yyyy
```

With `startswith` you can mimick `where col1 like m%`:

```
# df.query("col1.str.startswith('m')")                                                                                                  
# Out: 
#    col1  col2
# 1  many  many
```